# How to define that two token overlap in your lifetime?

Tags: identityserver4

When I refresh a token, then is the old one instant invalid. Correct?
Can I change this behavior? Can I define that the old token remains valid for 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlapping single-use refresh tokens is not something available out of the box but refresh token behavior is configurable via the `RefreshTokenUsage` property on the client. Single-use mode will mean that the old token will immediately be invalidated and a new one returned in the response. If you allow token re-use then the same token can be used until it expires.